# Not getting a result from SBTCookbook code from Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

Play Framework has, as part of their guides, this bit: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTCookbook#Hooking-into-Plays-dev-mode

It describes the creation of a `.scala` file in the `project/` folder, which allows you to execute some processes before starting the application in DEV mode.

So, I thought I'd try something simple like this:

```
import play.sbt.PlayRunHook
import sbt._

object Hello {
  def apply(base: File): PlayRunHook = {

    object HelloThere extends PlayRunHook {

      override def beforeStarted(): Unit = {
        Process("echo hello", base).run
      }
    }

    HelloThere
  }
}
```

File is saved as `Hello.scala`

But I'm not seeing anything in the console after running `activator run`. Am I doing something wrong? I did go to the `localhost:9000` url in the browser to see if that caused the compilation of anything more, but no results from that either.

Using Play 2.5.8

I have no experience in Scala, only Java. Though there doesn't seem anything wrong with the code. It's just a copy paste with the object name replaced and the process text replaced.

Comment: Did you register it in `build.sbt` as per the docs? I only ask since you did not include any config.

Comment: @Nio That was it. Don't understand how I missed that.

Comment: ;) Happens to me all the time!